# gRPC Context cancellation propogation

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I am trying to understand how Go context cancellation works underneath in client service communication (say, any gRPC API call ).

Let's say a client canceled the context on its end. Does it result in a new HTTP request to the server communicating the context of the previous/ongoing gRPC request is canceled? How does server knows if client cancelled the context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the `HTTP2` is used as the underneath protocol for gPRC. And there could be multiple streams in on `HTTP2` connection. Here is one image illustrate the connection and stream of `HTTP2` from [web dev](https://web.dev/performance-http2/)

[image]

If you cancel the context in one gRPC call before the response comes back. The errCode could be `CANCEL` and [mapping to `RST_STREAM`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md) on client side, then this `RST_STREAM` would be sent to server. The `RST_STREAM` frame allows for immediate termination of a stream, which is the current RPC call stream would be terminated. However, the `HTTP2` connection still there, when the next RPC call is invoked, another new stream will used to do the RPC call.

---

Here are some test codes snippet.

Client side: force to cancel context after 100 millseconds.

```golang
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(serverAddr,
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))

    defer conn.Close()

    c := pb.NewGreeterClient(conn)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.TODO())
        go func() {
            // force call cancel after 100 milliseconds
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
            cancel()
        }()

        r, err := c.SayHello(ctx, &pb.HelloRequest{Name: "name"})
     }
```

Server side: delay sayHello response in 1 second.

```golang
func (s *server) SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *pb.HelloRequest) (*pb.HelloReply, error) {
    // Delay ack on server by 1 seconds
    randMS := 1000

    select {
    case <-time.After(time.Duration(randMS) * time.Millisecond):

    case <-ctx.Done():
        if ctx.Err() == context.Canceled || ctx.Err() == context.DeadlineExceeded {
            log.Printf("SayHello: context err %+v \n", ctx.Err())
            return nil, ctx.Err()
            
        }
    }
```

Run the codes with  `GODEBUG=http2debug=2`, more debug logs of gRPC could help us to know the message between client and server.

---

Client logs

```
2022/10/21 20:40:38 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: wrote SETTINGS len=0
2022/10/21 20:40:38 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: read SETTINGS len=6, settings: MAX_FRAME_SIZE=16384
2022/10/21 20:40:38 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: wrote SETTINGS flags=ACK len=0
2022/10/21 20:40:38 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: read SETTINGS flags=ACK len=0
2022/10/21 20:40:38 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: wrote HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=1 len=98
2022/10/21 20:40:38 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: wrote DATA flags=END_STREAM stream=1 len=12 data="\x00\x00\x00\x00\a\n\x05world"
2022/10/21 20:40:38 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: read WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=12
2022/10/21 20:40:38 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: read PING len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2022/10/21 20:40:38 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: wrote PING flags=ACK len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
force call cancel in client
2022/10/21 20:40:38 could not greet: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2022/10/21 20:40:38 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: wrote RST_STREAM stream=1 len=4 ErrCode=CANCEL
2022/10/21 20:40:41 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: wrote HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=3 len=7
2022/10/21 20:40:41 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: wrote DATA flags=END_STREAM stream=3 len=12 data="\x00\x00\x00\x00\a\n\x05world"
2022/10/21 20:40:41 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: read WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=12
2022/10/21 20:40:41 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: read PING len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2022/10/21 20:40:41 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: wrote PING flags=ACK len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
force call cancel in client
2022/10/21 20:40:41 could not greet: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2022/10/21 20:40:41 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: wrote RST_STREAM stream=3 len=4 ErrCode=CANCEL
2022/10/21 20:40:44 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: wrote HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=5 len=7
2022/10/21 20:40:44 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: wrote DATA flags=END_STREAM stream=5 len=12 data="\x00\x00\x00\x00\a\n\x05world"
2022/10/21 20:40:44 http2: Framer 0xc0005be000: read WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=12
```

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say a client canceled the context on its end. Does it result in a new HTTP request to the server communicating the context of the previous/ongoing GRPC request is canceled?

No. It closes the network connection.

> How does server knows if client cancelled the context?

By virtue of the fact that the network connection was closed.

Comment: The response below by zangw  explains it better. Since multiple streams use the same connection, the connection is not closed simply by canceling the context on a single stream.